# Receive Response from Custom STS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I worked this http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx custom STS with windows foundation identity claims out.

If I understood correct the Identiy Access tool adds to the web.conf the neccessary references to the Identity Provider. When an user is calling the relying party's website, the idendity services checks if the user is logged in local. If not the user will be redirected to the STS btw. the identity providers login page. (for this no code writing is required)

If the login on the STS worked fine it sends a xml response with the neccassary data for the service provider (relay party).

1. How can I fetch the result / response from the STS on the service provider? The tutorials service provider mvc example contains only an empty Home Controller/view.
2. How can I create unprotected pages on the service provider? Is it sufficient adding Anonymous attributes to the action methods?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have to if you have the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` in the pipeline. If not, you'd have to handle the response manually and this could be a challenge if you have never done that.
2. Yes, the anonymous attribute should do fine.